# Python, converting SQLite into a txt file without symbols

Tags: python, sqlite

I was wondering how I could convert SQLite into a easily readable .txt file format. I was wondering how I could go about doing this as when I tried I either got a few errors or it would convert but leave in symbols making it harder for someone (who does not know code) to read.

Here is my current code:

```
#Modules
import hashlib
import sqlite3
#Database setup
db = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
c = db.cursor()
#Creating the table and columns
c.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users
            (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
             username TEXT, password TEXT)
            ''')

def register():
    username = input("Please create a username: ")
    realpass = input("Please create a password: ").encode('utf-8')
    hexpass = hashlib.sha256(realpass)
    password = hexpass.hexdigest()
    c.execute('''INSERT INTO  Users(username, password)
            VAlUES(?,?)''', (username, password)) 
    db.commit()#Saving the DB
    start()


def login():
    username = input("Please enter a username: ")
    realpass = input("Please enter a password: ").encode('utf-8')
    hexpass = hashlib.sha256(realpass)
    password = hexpass.hexdigest()
    finduser =('SELECT  FROM Users WHERE username = ? AND password =?')
    c.execute(finduser,[(username), (password)])
    results = c.fetchall()
    if results: 
        print("Welcome " +username)
        question()
    else: 
        print("Sorry wrong login details.")
        start()


def start():
    start1 = input("1.Register 2.Login: ")
    if start1 == "1":
        register()
    elif start1 == "2":
        login()
    else:
        print("Sorry invalid option")
        start()

start()
```

Comment: i tried hard to match the question and the given code, what do you need exactly ?

Comment: I am trying to open the .db file and turn all of the data from there into a readable .txt file. This is what I want it to look like https://pastebin.com/JUfkwyv5 . The password section would be in sha256 form not saying (Sha256) its just I haven't got the time to translate the hashes at the moment.

Comment: looks like you need something like the csv format to extract these informations in a readable way

Comment: How could one go about that?

Comment: you can fetch all the resuts of a query like `SELECT * FROM Users` and convert them in list of strings to dump them in a csv file with the classic methods [`writerows` or `writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects). Please take a look at the standard doc, try something and then update your question when you will be stuck.